# Why is it printing the last element in circular linked list?

Tags: c++

In the below code, the number stored inside the last element is only being displayed, not the rest of elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
   int data;
   node* next;
};

struct node * Start = NULL;
struct node * End = NULL;
void CreateList(int num)
{
   struct node *temp = new struct node;
   int data,i=0;
   while(true)
   {
      cout<<"Enter data \n";
      cin>>data;
      temp->data = data;
      temp->next = Start;
      if(Start==NULL)
      {
         Start = End = temp;
      }
      else{
         End->next = temp;
         End = temp;

      }
      if(i==num-1)
         break;

      i++;
   }
}

void Display()
{
   struct node* temp1;
   temp1 = Start;
   do{
      cout<<temp1->data<<endl;
      temp1=temp1->next;
   } while(temp1!=Start);
}

int main()
{
   int num;
   cout<<"How many elements you want to input?\n";
   cin>>num;
   CreateList(num);
   Display();
   return 0;
}
```

I have done it using structure not classes. I have used two non-dynamic pointers 'Start' and 'End'. The main problem is coming in `Display()` function. The `Display()` is printing the value of the last element.

Output:

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating the required number of nodes in `CreateList`. You are creating a node using

```
struct node *temp = new struct node;
```

and are reusing the same node in the loop.

Here's an updated version of the function.

```
void CreateList(int num)
{
   int data,i=0;
   while(true)
   {
      cout<<"Enter data \n";
      cin>>data;

      // Create a new node for every data
      struct node *temp = new struct node;

      temp->data = data;
      temp->next = Start;

      if(Start==NULL)
      {
         Start = End = temp;
      }
      else{
         End->next = temp;
         End = temp;

      }
      if(i==num-1)
         break;

      i++;
   }
}
```

---

Suggestion for futher cleanup. In C++, you don't need to use `struct node`. Just `node` is sufficient.

```
node* Start = NULL;
node* End = NULL;
```

and

```
// Create a new node for every data
node *temp = new node;
```